# Empty Mime-type while uploading file in React js application in Windows OS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I am using the following HTML code in react application to upload files :

```
<div className="form-group files">
     <label>Upload Your File </label>
     <input type="file" className="form-control" multiple onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
</div>
```

This code is runnig fine in lynux os for uplaoding (doc and docx) files: Sample output for uploading the docx file from Ubuntu machine is:

```
File {
       ​ lastModified: 1585969775000
    ​    name: "Resume_2.docx"
       ​ size: 122424
       ​ **type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"**
    ​    ...
    }
```

But when I am trying to run the same code on Windows OS, it seems to be BUG in a code, as I am not getting the expected output.
Here is the output on windows machine

```
File {
       ​ lastModified: 1585968960500
    ​    name: "Resume_2.docx"
       ​ size: 122424
       ​ **type: ""**
    ​    ...
    }
```

The **typ**e attribute is **EMPTY**. This is same is the output for .doc, .csv, .ppt, .pptx etc files.
Though this code is working fine for .pdf, .jpg, .png, .txt files.

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/denyshubh/ResumeReader/blob/master/src/App.jsx) to Complete Code.

Answer (score 0):

The best was if you use form data

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('profileFileSrc', this.state.filesrc);
```

then make a method like this

```
handleProfileChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        filesrc: event.target.files[0]
    })
}
```

Under render

```
   <input  type="file"  onChange={this.handleProfileChange} />
```

Comment: Thank You, Sagar, I'll try and update you. If possible, could you please let me know why this problem occured.  Why things are working fine in Lynux but not on windows machine.

Comment: Its maybe file system difference